# MySQL Continuosuly crahsing

Tags: windows, mysql

I am continuously receiving below error in event viewer... from which it stop mysql service...

This is the following error,

**Faulting application mysqld-nt.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module mysqld-nt.exe, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x0022401c.**

When I checked MySQL error log file, there is no ERROR or WARNING message regarding crash, it is showing normal shutdown.

Can any help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

MySql 5.0 on Windows Server 2003 kept crashing while running a procedure.  I found the issue within the procedure.  I was ordering the data retrieved from multiple UNIONS on a column that did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything. Here is one example: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,28729,115538#msg-115538

mysqld-nt.exe is quite old, are you using version 4.x?

The only option I can give you is to use a debug compiled MySQL version to hopefully get more information about the crash in terms of a stack trace BUT in reality you should upgrade that MySQL version to 5.1.

Comment: No, I am using MySQL 5.0.24.